why kubectl run onfail1 --image=alpine --restart=OnFailure -- exit 0， pod status=CrashLoopBackOff， i think should be completed
enter image description here
kubectl run onfail1 --image=alpine --restart=OnFailure -- exit 0.
finally, this pod status=CrashLoopBackOff.
i think should be completed, because exit code = 0, so this pod not restart.
why? this status should be completed. could you tell me why?

you can see the error with the command:
kubectl describe pods onfail1

The error is caused beacuse the command 'exit' is not found in $PATH.
You can edit your command as below and the pod will complete succesfully
kubectl run onfail1 --image=alpine --restart=OnFailure -- echo "Hello world"


For a pod to enter a Completed state, it should not be restarted upon successful completion. Here’s how you can achieve this:
Solution 1: Use kubectl create job
Use a Kubernetes Job, which is designed to run a task to completion:
kubectl create job onfail1 --image=alpine -- /bin/sh -c "exit 0"

Solution 2: Use kubectl run with --restart=Never
kubectl run onfail1 --image=alpine --restart=Never -- /bin/sh -c "exit 0"

--restart=OnFailure: This restarts the pod if it exits with a non-zero exit code, which may lead to unexpected restarts and CrashLoopBackOff if the container exits too quickly.
--restart=Never: This prevents the pod from being restarted, allowing it to complete successfully and show a Completed status.
